# Populating HTML table with Google Sheet data (rows & columns)

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Having issues with what it might be a rather easy fix.

- **Context**: My code is currently pulling data from Google Sheets, crafting some sort of table and sending it back to HTML where it repopulates an already existing table.
- **Issue**: I am unable to make it so that it builds columns as well as rows. It pastes the data back all in one go (see image for context).
- **Files**: GS & HTML. I believe the issue is on how I'm crafting the table. I know the current disposition of '' doesn't make sense, bu

**HTML table with Gsheet values:**
[image: HTML table with GSheet values]

**Original Gsheet table:**
[image: Original Gsheet table]

**Google Script**

```js
function populateStratTb2(){
  var tablerows = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('supp_str').getRange(1, 5, 1000).getValue();
  var tablevalues = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('supp_str').getRange(4, 1, tablerows).getValues();
  var tvlen = tablevalues.length

 
  var active = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = active.getSheetByName("supp_str");
  var myRange = sheet.getRange("d3:m" + tvlen); 
  var data    = myRange.getValues();
  var optionsHTML = "";

for ( var r = 0; r < 10; r+=1) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=1) {
    optionsHTML += '<tr><td>' + data[i][r] + '</td></tr>';
  }};
   return optionsHTML;

}
```

**HTML Script**

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
   $(function(){
     google.script.run
       .withSuccessHandler(displayData)
       .populateStratTb2();
   });
   function displayData(hl){
     document.getElementById('strattable').innerHTML=hl;
   }
   console.log('MyCode');
   </script>
```

PS. I have spent a good couple hours scrolling though the forum picking bits and improving my original code. I am sure this question (or similar) has been answered already but I can't manage to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modifications?

#### Modification 1:

If your for loop is used, how about the following modification?

```js
function populateStratTb2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('supp_str');
  var tablerows = sheet.getRange(1, 5, 1000).getValue();
  var tablevalues = sheet.getRange(4, 1, tablerows).getValues();
  var tvlen = tablevalues.length
  var myRange = sheet.getRange("d3:m" + tvlen);
  var data = myRange.getValues();
  var optionsHTML = "";
  for (var r = 0; r < 10; r += 1) {
    var row = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
      row += '<td>' + data[i][r] + '</td>';
    }
    optionsHTML += '<tr>' + row + '</tr>';
  }
  optionsHTML = '<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse">' + optionsHTML + "</table>";
  return optionsHTML;
}
```

- I'm worried that your for loop might not be your expected result. So, I would like to proposed one more modified script as "Modification 2".

#### Modification 2:

If your `data` is converted to the HTML table, how about the following modification?

```js
function populateStratTb2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('supp_str');
  var tablerows = sheet.getRange(1, 5, 1000).getValue();
  var tablevalues = sheet.getRange(4, 1, tablerows).getValues();
  var tvlen = tablevalues.length
  var myRange = sheet.getRange("d3:m" + tvlen);
  var data = myRange.getValues();
  var optionsHTML = '<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse">' + data.reduce((s, r) => s += "<tr>" + r.map(c => `<td>${c}</td>`).join("") + "</tr>", "") + "</table>";
  return optionsHTML;
}
```

#### Note:

- If you don't want to add the border, please modify `<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse">` to `<table>`.
- From your reply, I added 2 sample scripts for the script for obtaining the same result from `reduce` and `for loop` as follows.

  - `reduce`

    ```
      var optionsHTML = '<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse">' + data.reduce((s, r) => s += "<tr>" + r.map(c => `<td>${c}</td>`).join("") + "</tr>", "") + "</table>";
    ```
  - `for loop`

    ```
      var optionsHTML = "";
      for (var r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
        var row = "";
        for (var c = 0; c < data[r].length; c++) {
          row += '<td>' + data[r][c] + '</td>';
        }
        optionsHTML += '<tr>' + row + '</tr>';
      }
      optionsHTML = '<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse">' + optionsHTML + "</table>";
    ```

#### Reference:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: The for loop wasn't working well indeed, but the second one does it! At this point Im honestly more interested in the solution than the fix itself. I'm curious as to how does the Mod 2 work without ant for loop. (For context, I don't know neither reduce, map nor join). Any further context would be much appreciated! Thanks a lot for the solution BTW.

Comment: @A. Prats Thank you for replying. About `reduce`, you can see the document at [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). And also, I added 2 sample scripts for the script for obtaining the same result from `reduce` and `for loop`. If that was useful, I'm glad.

Comment: @A. Prats Thank you for replying. If that is useful, I'm glad.